# Mathematica can't solve this system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve this system but I can't

```
Solve[(1 - x^2) (-W - 3 x + Sqrt[6] Sqrt[z])
   == 
   -W^4 x (-1 + x^2) y +
   3 W y (W^3 (-1 + x^2) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - x^2] y) - 
   6 Sqrt[6] (y + Sqrt[1 - x^2] (-1 + z))^2 Sqrt[z] + 
   W^3 (-1 + x^2) z) 
   == 
   9 Sqrt[6] (y + Sqrt[1 - x^2] (-1 + z))^2 (1 - 2 z) Sqrt[z] 
   -1/3 W^3 (-1 + x^2) z (Sqrt[6] W x 
   - 9 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - x^2] y + z)) 
   ==
   3 W (W^3 (-1 + x^2) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - x^2] y) - 
   6 Sqrt[6] (y + Sqrt[1 - x^2] (-1 + z))^2 Sqrt[z] + 
   W^3 (-1 + x^2) z)
   == 0, {x, y, z, W}]
```

Comment: it does not appear to be a system ie a list of equations but a single expression with consecutive `Equal` signs.Consider breaking up the successive equalities into their corresponding parts ie transform  `x==y==z` into `{x==y,y==z,x==z}`

Comment: @user42582 That's not a problem.  It's valid syntax.  (BTW it can be expanded using `LogicalExpand`.)  I believe that reason why `Solve` is so slow that after eliminating all the square roots it ends up with a high order polynomial system of equations with complicated coefficients.  It is simply too slow to work with such large expressions.  This also means that the solution would look uselessly complicated, so it's not worth computing the exact symbolic result.

Comment: Evidence for this is also the high memory usage of the kernel when evaluating this `Solve`.  On my machine it keeps hovering around 1 GB (going up and down) after running for a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Szabolcs you are right , when run this code about all of my RAM and a large part of my CPU used. I am waiting for about 1 hour with any result.

Comment: I suggest you use `NSolve`. It also took a long time but it finished and found 967 solutions.  I don't know if this solution set is exhaustive.

Comment: @Szabolcs : Unfortunately, I can't realize NSolve. It crashes my intermediate comp in short time.

Comment: @Szabolcs , of the 976 do any have non-zero `W`?  see if you get any solutions if you divide eq 2&4 by `W`..   ( You must have a better computer than me! )

Comment: `NSolve` might not recognize that it has an infinite solution set with one and two dimensional components.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Making use of`FindRoot` instead of `Solve`, one obtains by

```
FindRoot[{sys}, {{x, 0.1} , {y, 0.1}, {z, 0.1}, {W,0.1}}]
```

{x -> 0.57735, y -> 0.100001, z -> 0.5, W -> 9.21509*10^(-18)}.

Addition. Subsituting W->2 in the system and NSolving it in $x,y,z$, one obtains

NSolve::infsolns: Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1. Returning intersection of solutions with -((121484 x)/178835)-(113492 y)/178835+(171802 z)/178835 == 1.

and

{{x -> 1., y -> -2.64617, z -> 0.}, {x -> -1., y -> -0.505331, 
  z -> 0.}, {x -> -1., y -> 0., z -> 0.33382}, {x -> -1., y -> 0., 
  z -> 0.33382}, {x -> -1., y -> 0., z -> 0.33382}, {x -> 1., y -> 0.,
   z -> 1.74805}, {x -> 1., y -> 0., z -> 1.74805}, {x -> 1., y -> 0.,
   z -> 1.74805}}

Addition 2. By the  changes `Sqrt[z]==s` and `Sqrt[1-x^2]==t` the system under consideration  can be reduced to a polynomial system over Q(Sqrt[6]). The reduced system can be solved in terms of higher degree polynomials via Groebner  on powerful comp. It is clear that solution would be huge and useless. I find it monkey business.

Comment: There are at least 6 real solutions of the system under consideration.

Comment: Thanks, The "Find Root" find one solution but I think this system have more answers

Comment: @ milad : Do you really need all the ones?

Comment: Yes, I am studying dynamical system of a model in cosmology and I must check all answers for investigate this model is good or no

Comment: @ milad : Then how about the case when the solution set is infinite?

Comment: you can see `W=0` eliminates two equations, so there will likely be infinite solutions there.

Comment: @user64494 I don't konw really what do I do....

Comment: @george2079 I can't eliminate W this is important and x,y,z  are too

Comment: if you require only solutions with `w!=0` you should add that constraint to the question.