# Does NSolve find all solutions?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Is the solution set returned by `NSolve` usually complete?  Can I assume that there are no more solutions than what it returns?  Consider systems of equations e.g. like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129658/12).

I expect that the answer is either generally "no" or that it depends on the type of equations (polynomial? exact coefficients?), on the method being used, and on other settings (such as [`VerifySolutions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerifySolutions.html)).  So the better question is: in which cases (if any) can I assume that `NSolve` found all solutions?

It is clear that the solution values are approximate but it is not clear that the *number of solutions* is also approximate.  Multiple roots are generally returned with the correct multiplicity.

Comment: Here's a relatively innocuous case where it fails: `NSolve[Product[1.1^n x - 1., {n, 20}] == 0 && 0 < x < 1, x] // Length`. I don't know how to predict that it would fail....

Comment: @MichaelE2 Not only `NSolve`, but also `Solve` fails for this.  It's strange that after removing the constraint of `0 < x < 1` it works.  With exact coefficients it also works.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `NRoots` also works with all three documented methods.  Maybe the constraint triggers a switch to a different method?  Somehow this really feels like a bug but then I am not familiar with the numerical intricacies of finding polynomial roots and the coefficients do span 10 orders of magnitude.

Comment: Another example is ClearAll; NSolve[Sin[1/(x + 10^(-5))] == 0 && x > 0 && x < 1, x] // Length

Comment: @user64494 OK, it's clear enough that there are many examples when it fails.  I wonder if there are any cases when we can trust it, e.g. polynomial with exact coefficients and no inequalities.  Or things like `Sqrt[x] == 2` which is not exactly polynomial but clearly related as its solutions are a subset of the solutions of `x == 2^2`.  (Not sure what these are called).  With a single polynomial equation the number of roots is clear.  I don't know about a system or cases like the $\sqrt{x} = 2$ above.

Comment: @user64494 There are internal constraints that limit the number of solutions found. This gets them all: `SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"IntervalRootsOptions" -> {"MaxIncomplete" -> 35000, "MaxSteps" -> 150000}}]; NSolve[Sin[1/(x + 10^(-5))] == 0 && x > 0 && x < 1, x] // Length`.

Comment: @ Micael E2: Thank you. Now I know more. However, one may decrease 10^(-5) to 10^(-20). In general, the total number of solutions is apriori unknown.

Comment: @Szabolcs I would have thought `NSolve` would be reliable on polynomials up to precision constraints. Perhaps it is on unbounded problems. I would also have thought `NSolve` would be reliable on the roots of transcendental functions over a compact domain, provided the function is analytic in a sufficiently large complex neighborhood of the domain and working precision is sufficiently high. My example, which is similar to [Wilkinson's second polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial#Wilkinson.27s_second_example), rather undermines my assumptions.

Comment: @user64494 My point is simply that there are such limits that are programmed and not numerical limitations of the algorithms. However, when you get exactly 1000 solutions, you might wonder if you hit the limit and try increasing it. The other limits are harder to detect. It does not appear there is a way to get `NSolve` to tell you when it's run into such a limit, which is too bad. -- A site tip: if you don't put a space between the @ and my name, I'll get notified of your reply.

Comment: There might be version dependence, too. In the comments and answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129049/help-with-solving-trascendental-equations-involving-bessels-equations), `NSolve`found all answers in an interval in v10.0 but not in v10.4. Now, granted, `NSolve` is not designed to solve transcendental equations, but the version-dependence is still a little strange.